# Get the version of MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, version

ALL,

Is there a query which will give me the version of the mdb/accdb file created?

Or this info is not stored anywhere?

Background:

I'm working on C++ program, connecting with ODBC driver and want to know ACCESS version behind this file.

TIA!!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

It has been requested from many to have an option to check if a database file supports, say, *BigInt* or *DateTime2* but, currently, you are left with trial-n-error.

However, if you don't plan to modify the scheme, your only concern should be, if the database file is of the old **mdb** (JET) form or the newer (introduced 14 years ago) **accdb** (ACE) format.

Comment: I am planning to modify it.

Comment: Via ODBC, your option is an Alter query. Same syntax for both engines, so it should be a  driver question only.

Comment: what both engines? I'm asking about `ACCESS` only. Or you are taking about `accdb` vs `mdb`. Also what is this `ALTER` query? Or you are saying I should use ALTER TABLE for table changes?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned. In SQL you use the `Alter ...` syntax to modify (alter) the schema.

Comment: ok, understood. No way to get ACCESS engine version outside of VB/DAO. Will look at that. Thank you.

Comment: You should safely be able to detect it from the file extension. It is extremely uncommon to name files differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily obtain that information using DAO, the `Database.Version` property.

In vbscript, that'd look like this:

```vb
Dim dbe
Set dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DbEngine")
Dim db
Set db = dbe.OpenDatabase("C:\Path\To\Db.accdb")
WScript.Echo db.Version 'E.g. 14.0 for Office 2010
```

Using COM is a lot more verbose in C++ so I'll leave that to you, but the approach could be the same.

Using only ODBC, I'm not sure how to obtain this information, though.